# ASP.NET Language Toggle

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm able to change the language for my pages, however if I select french and I am on a current page and if I try to load another page, that page won't be in french. How can I set it so it is consistent throught?

Toggle Button in master page:
        If Page.Culture = "English (United States)" Then
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?lang=fr-CA")
        ElseIf Page.Culture = "French (Canada)" Then
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?lang=en-US")
        End If

and in every page:

Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        Dim lang As String = String.Empty

```
    lang = Request.QueryString("lang")

    If lang IsNot Nothing Then

        Session("culture") = lang
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo(lang)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(lang)

    Else

        If Session("culture") IsNot Nothing Then

            lang = Session("culture").ToString()
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo(lang)
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(lang)
        End If
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
    End If
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we see some code on how you are trying to load and saving the language? There could a number of different reasons why this isn't working and without showing anything I can't see how anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the querystring parameters are not posted back when changing from page as aposed to toggling in the master page.

Can you try and debug the application to see what your Request.QueryString collection is when changing from page?

Maybe a better way to store the culture would be in a cookie or (if your using asp.net membership) in the users profile.

May I also note that a base page would be handy to implement the InitializeCulture method instead of repeating it in every page if that's the case.

Comment: Has this resolved your problem or was it caused by something else?